# UE5: import csv for a data driven animation

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I was wondering if UE5 can support 50k+ lines of a db/CSV as they rappresent the parameters of the whole animation. (coordinates[x,y,z], TimeDelta, Speed, Brake)
Any documentation is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no existing functionality in the engine itself for this extremely specific use case. Of course, it can "support" it if you write a custom solution using the many available tools within the engine.

You can use `IFileHandle` to stream in a file (your csv): [link](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/GenericPlatform/IFileHandle/)

You can then parse the incoming data to create a `FVector3` of your coordinates, a `float` of your TimeDelta, etc. For example, `FVector::InitFromString` may help: [link](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Math/FVector/InitFromString/)

However, this depends very much on the format of your data. Parsing string/texts into values is not specific to UE4, you can find a lot of info on converting streams of binary/character data to needed values.

Applying the animation as the data is read is a separate, quite big, task. Since you provide no details on what the animation data represents, or what you need to apply it to, I cannot really help.

In general though, it can help you a lot to break down your question into 3-4 separate, more specific, questions. In any case though, this is a task that will require a lot of research and work.

And even before that, it might be good to research alternative approaches and changing the pipeline, to avoid using such non-standard file structures for animation.